# Criando input automaticamente limitando em 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou criando dois campos input quando clico no botão mais (+) , já consigo gerar os dois inputs, mas preciso limitar o mesmo, apenas 5 input que eu preciso, já tentei com while e não obtive sucesso, segue o codigo, obrigado

/*cria mais campos valor do aditivo e numero de parcelas*/

```
function duplicarCampos(){  
    var clone = document.getElementById('origem').cloneNode(true);  
    var destino = document.getElementById('destino');  
    destino.appendChild (clone);  

    var camposClonados = clone.getElementsByTagName('input');  

    for(i=0; i<camposClonados.length;i++){  
        camposClonados[i].value = '';  
    }  

}  

    <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <div align="center" style="font-size:12px;background: #FFDAB9;border: 1px solid rgb(161, 161, 161) " id="origem"  > 
                    <br>
                    Valor do Aditívo (R$):  <input type="text" id="tco_valor_aditivo_new" name="tco_valor_aditivo_new[]"  maxlength="14" size="14"/><br>
                    <br>
                    Número de Parcelas:
                    <select name="tco_num_parcelas" id="tco_num_parcelas" >
                        <option value="...">...</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                    </select>
                    <p>
                    <button type="button" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="duplicarCampos();">+</button>
                    <button type="button" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="removerCampos(this);">-</button>
                    <p><p><p>
                </div> 
            <div id="destino"></div> 
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Poderia postar o código completo?

Comment: Você pode criar uma variável global que vai contanto os `inputs` adicionados. Também pode buscar o número de `inputs` dentro de um elemento pai. Por exemplo buscar o número de `inputs` dentro da `div` "destino".

Comment: Earendul voce pode mostrar um exemplo ? obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode buscar o número de `inputs` dentro de um elemento pai. Por exemplo buscar o número de `inputs` dentro da `div` "destino".

Exemplo:

```
function duplicarCampos(){ 
   var count = $("#destino input").length;
   if (count <= 5) {
      var clone = document.getElementById('origem').cloneNode(true);  
      var destino = document.getElementById('destino');  
      destino.appendChild (clone);  
   }
   var camposClonados = clone.getElementsByTagName('input');  
}
```

Comment: obrigado Earendul, deu certo ! abraços

Answer (score 3):

Tenta fazer o seguinte, adiciona um atributo data no seu button.

```
<button type="button" data-index="0" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="removerCampos(this);">-</button>


function duplicarCampos(event){  
    var clone = document.getElementById('origem').cloneNode(true);  
    var destino = document.getElementById('destino');  
    destino.appendChild (clone);
    var dataIndex = event.getAttribute("data-index");

    if(dataIndex > 5){
       var camposClonados = clone.getElementsByTagName('input');

       for(i=0; i<camposClonados.length;i++){  
          camposClonados[i].value = '';  
       } 
    }
    dataIndex++;
    event.setAttribute("data-index",dataIndex);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Vinícius Montanheiro pela contribuição, abraços.

Comment: Por nada amigo. Abração.